# How to I get access to the `previous` method for a link?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to follow the railscast for [Nested Model Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast) but I am running into a problem writing the `Java Script`. I have been working with `Rails` for a couple of weeks now but this is the first time I have encountered `JavaScript`, so forgive me if this sounds a little nubbish.

I am trying to remove elements from the form as the cast suggests but it is giving me the following error. (I am using Chrome's debugging tools to view the errors)

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'previous' application.js?body=1:10222
> remove_class_row application.js?body=1:10222
> onclick read:95

This is my view, /app_root/app/views/classifications/read.html.erb:

```
<table id="classification_read_table">
    <tr ><td id="classification_read_table_td">
        <b>Classification</b>
    </td></tr>
    <%= form_tag read_build_path  %>
        <% @classes.each do |f| %>
            <div class="class_row">
                <tr >
                    <td class="classification_read_table_td">
                        <%= fields_for "class_is[]", f do |g| %>
                        <%= g.label :name %>
                        <%= g.text_field :name %>
                        <%= g.hidden_field :_destroy%>
                        <%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_class_row(this)" %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

This is my JS file app_root/app/assets/javascript/application.js:

```
function remove_class_row(link) {
    $(link).previous("input[type=hidden]").value = "1"; //Error on this line: 
    $(link).up(".class_row").hide();
}
```

I'm doing the javascript just as the rails cast shows, so I don't understand what might be going wrong. My first thoughts are that what I'm trying to do my be deprecated? Or for some reason my HTML isn't being set up in the right way.

Hopefully someone can point out the mundane detail that I am missing.

Thanks!!

Comment: How would I know if I'm using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for `.prev()`. Also, you should use `.val()` to set a field value with jQuery.

```
$(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
```

Comment: Well that seemed to take away the error on that line but now it is giving the same error for `up` :\ any ideas?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of the RailsCast and use the **Alternate jQuery Code**. The code in the main part of the RailsCast uses Prototype, which was the default framework for Rails apps at the time, but it has since been changed to jQuery.

Comment: You are looking for the parent element with class `class_row`, right? Try `.parents()`. More info: http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: ohhhhhhhh That would make more sense!!